# rails 3 named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am upgrading my application to rails 3.  My old route was

```
map.profile 'profile/:login', :controller => 'profile', :action => 'show'
```

I changed this to:

```
 match 'profile/:login', :to => 'profile#show'
```

This works when I enter in the route say /profile/red99

But when I use a generic link like:

```
 <%= link_to image.user.login, :controller => "profile", :action => image.user.login %>
```

or

```
 <%= link_to "public profile", :controller => "profile", :action => current_user.login %>
```

I gives me the error No route matches {:controller=>"profile", :action=>"red99"}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the URL for the profile you still need to use the parameters:

```
:controller => 'profile', :action => 'show', :login => current_user.login
```

You haven't changed the `action` parameter by defining that route, you've simply made a more readable URL by implicitly specifying the action.